# solution and sqlite for stand alone client files to install

Tags: c#, excel, sqlite

I just finished an application for a stand alone user to automate the filling of an Excel spread sheet. The application is in c# and the database is SQLite. Now I have to install the solution in the client PC. I was reading this site and I have done some recommendations. For example, I installed System.Data.SQLite X86 and X64. But I have some question yet: what files do I have to copy to the folder I'm going to use to install the solution in the client PC.

- I have to copy the .exe VS creates when compiles the c# solution.
- .NET Framework 4.5
- SQLite database

Please, what other files do I have to add to that folder?

Comment: You don't need to install System.Data.SQLLite onto the users machine - just copy the db driver dll into the same folder as your executable.

Comment: Ok, but what is the path of my database in the new PC? how to express that in my application?

Comment: Have the SQLite database in the same folder as the assembly or a subfolder of that folder. When you define your connection string, set the data source property to be the relative path to the db file.

Comment: relative path? how is it? I found AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, I get the full path to my .exe, but what is the relative path?